# How to round array of values based on new range?

Tags: python

i have an array of two value. What I'm trying to do is round those values to 0 or 1, but based on another "range", not the commom one of bigger than 0.5. For example, in the second elements, if the value is bigger than 0.6, the value changes to 1 and the other changes to 0.

The array and the expected output are listed bellow:

```
array = [[0.7 , 0.3 ],
         [0.4 , 0.6],
         [0.45, 0.55]]
```

Expected array:

```
array = [[1 , 0 ],
         [0 , 1],
         [1, 0]]
```

Comment: You might need to explain further.  How does the last array go from `[0.45, 0.55]` to `[1, 0]`?  Obviously the two values are being rounded according to different rules -- where did those come from?  What's the "another range" you're talking about?

Comment: Also: what code have you tried so far, and what output did you get? How is it different than what you want?

Comment: Paulo Masnik, your question is not consistent. Eventually you may reformulate it as "how to update array values based on value dependent rules" I'm agreeing with Somwise

Answer (score 0):

I think you can iterate through the array and change each value depending on this new threshold.

```
threshold = 0.6
rows = len(array)
cols = len(array[0])
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        if array[i][j] >= threshold:
            array[i][j] = 1
        else:
            array[i][j] = 0
```